# Opencv cascade.detectMultiScale is not detecting the eyes

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some code using opencv for detecting faces and eyes. The full code is here (https://pastebin.com/s4zCN7gM), for those interested, but the specific area that I think is the problem is in the code-snippet below.

```
//Standardize the brightness and contrast to improve dark images.
  Mat equalizedImg;
  equalizeHist(inputImg, equalizedImg);

  imwrite(filename + "equalizeHist.png", inputImg);
  cout << "searchScaleFactor= "<< endl << " " << searchScaleFactor << endl << endl;
  cout << "minNeighbors= "<< endl << " " << minNeighbors << endl << endl;
  cout << "flags= "<< endl << " " << flags << endl << endl;
  cout << "minFeatureSize= "<< endl << " " << minFeatureSize << endl << endl;
  //Detect objects in the small grayscale image.
  cascade.detectMultiScale(equalizedImg, objects, searchScaleFactor,
                           minNeighbors, flags, minFeatureSize);
  cout << "object size= "<< endl << " " << objects.size() << endl << endl;
```

The above code works on some images but not all. I would like to understand why it is failing and whether or how I can imporve detection. Consider the image of tomcruise  on which I am applying this code. The original image is here: https://imagebin.ca/v/4vtXMOf7xAqT . The image of tom cruise has been grayscaled, and several processing steps performed before we arrive at the image created in the code snippet above, where 'equalizedImg' looks like: https://imagebin.ca/v/4vtXuQdEtoBR  .

The cascade.detectMultiscale() returns an objects of size 0 instead of 1 (when it detects something).

The initalized variables that cascade.detectMultiscale() needs are set as follows. I will say that I don't fully/clearly understand what these variables do or mean and whether these should be adjusted.

```
searchScaleFactor=1.1
minNeighbors=4
flags = 4
minFeatureSize=[20 x 20]
```

Comment: you'll have to train a better detector yourself.  You could try to reduce minNeighbors and searchScaleFactor and if in your images the eyes are smaller than 20x20 pixels you should try to resize the input image (make it bigger).

Answer (score 0):

Cascade detectors don't live up to modern standards of object detection. Do you care to try some of the more recent object detection models, e.g. https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/interactive_face_detection_demo ?

Comment: Hi, I am open to it, if the cascade classifier for eyes is really so bad that my current code cannot be improved. Also, I need to understand these new object detection models. What was nice about my code was it based on a book where the opencv face recognition was explained in detail. Do you have any suggestions on what I can refer to understand how to use these new object detection models?

Comment: I think the best thing there is so far is the demo code: https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/interactive_face_detection_demo Also, you can watch a video and follow the links from there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEntm0TUqM8 Though, these only show how to use the models and don't go into intricate details of how deep networks detect objects.